# HTML selected rectangle box

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have 4 Profession Prof A, Prof B, Prof C and Prof D.
[image]

What I want is that when a user clicks on the Prof A button, then the Prof A color would be a dark color and all the remaining colored buttons would be grey.

When I click on the next button, the selected Prof A would be saved to a database, the next button should require that a Prof button has been selected.

My profession.jsp page code is given below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Profession</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var reqJSONObj = '${reqJSONObj}';
        reqJSONObj = reqJSONObj.replace("/", "'");
        var _parseJson = JSON.parse(reqJSONObj);
        var orgName = _parseJson['orgName'];
        document.getElementById('lblsuccessMsg').innerHTML = "sucsess - '&lt;" + orgName + "&gt; has an agreement";
        if (reqJSONObj == "" || reqJSONObj == null) {
            window.location.href = "index.jsp";
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form_profession" action="org_name" method="post">
        <div class="container-fluid orgdiv">
            <div class="topgreen" style="">
                <p>
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span id="lblsuccessMsg"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class=" text-center topbgimage">
                <img src="images/bg.jpg" class="" style="max-width: 100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12  heading text-center"
                        style="text-align: center;">
                        <h1 class="">Profession</h1>
                        <p>
                            Select Your Profession So we can Provide you with appropriate service
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
                            <h2>Prof A</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
                            <h2>Prof B</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
                            <h2>Prof C</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
                            <h2>Prof D</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center footerdiv" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" class="bg-primary btn" name="btnProfession" id="btnProfession" value="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to (partially) replicate the functionality of radio buttons; therefore, you might want to start by looking into how they and `label` elements can be styled.

Comment: @AdrianWragg This functionality is like radio button but I don't want to show radio button Icon on this.

Comment: you dont have to show the radio button. You will hide them and play around only with its lables by giving it background color , then you will toggle this color according to if the radio button is checked or not.. A close example is here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/radio-button-tabs

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for the example, pretty much what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Reddy I use "<a href="javascript:inserProf('Prof A');" class="btn-info col-md-3 col-sm-3 box" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;"><h2>Prof A</h2></a>" in place of "<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 box"><h2>Prof A</h2></div>" By using this I am able to do color change when i click on any profession. But problem is that when i click on outside this form or any where my selected profession color change as by default.

Comment: Have you had a look at my provided answer? It changes the CSS value so even if you click away from the form it would stay as the selected dark blue colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/rredqa2k/1/

HTML

```
<body>
  <form id="form" name="form_profession" action="org_name" method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid orgdiv">
      <div class="topgreen" style="">
        <p>
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span id="lblsuccessMsg"></span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="a col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
              <h2 class="a">Prof A</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="b col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
              <h2 class="b">Prof B</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="c col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
              <h2 class="c">Prof C</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d col-md-3 col-sm-3 box">
              <h2 class="d">Prof D</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center footerdiv" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" class="bg-primary btn" name="btnProfession" id="btnProfession" value="Next" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```
h2{
  color:white;
}
.row{
  min-width:440px;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:4%;
}

.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
  padding:2%;
  border-radius:12px;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}

#btnProfession{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius:12px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  width:20%;
  padding:2%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.row').on('click',function(e){
   $('.a, .b, .c, .d').css('backgroundColor','gray');
   $("." + e.target.className[0]).css('backgroundColor','darkblue');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to store the selected answer anywhere.